# How do I unit test a private Cocoapods library?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, swift5

I am trying to find out how to set up unit testing for my private cocoapod library.

Here is the expecting result:

I added a unit testing target 'MyPodTests' to the 'Pods' Project, then I changed target to my 'MyPodTests' scheme. Then I created test classes for my unit tests. I can now select my 'MyPodLib' scheme and press CMD+U and the testing target executes the tests. This is the behavior I am looking for.

This approach, however, has some drawbacks. If I do 'pod update' or 'pod install' on my example app, the test target is gone. if I call pod update on my Example application, the tests are gone too. I'm certain there is a correct way to do this. Also, I would like to prevent the test classes from being loaded into any consumers using the library, therefore I added an exclusion to my podspec:

```
s.exclude_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/Test/*'
```

When I select MyPodLib and press CMD+U nothing is happening, and if I select MyPodTests and press CMD+U it throws "No such module 'MyPodLib'" error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to have the tests running independently of your example app. If that's the case add a test subspec in your pod spec and set its source files.

For example, say you have an Xcode project with a framework target MyFramework and a test target MyFrameworkTests. Your pod spec will look like this:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name           = "MyFramework"
  s.version        = "1.0.0"
  s.summary        = "Summary of what MyFramework does"
  s.homepage       = "https://www.website.com"
  s.license        = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENCE.txt" }
  s.author         = "Ramesh Boosa"
  s.platform       = :ios, "11.0"
  s.swift_versions = ["5.0", "5.1"]
  s.source         = { :git => "https://github.com/MyName/MyFramework.git", :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files   = "MyFramework/*.swift"
  s.test_spec do|test|
    test.source_files = "MyFrameworkTests/*.swift"
  end
end
```

To lint your pod spec and to run your unit tests execute `pod spec lint MyFramework.podspec`.

If your example app is included with your pod you can add an app host to your podspec. The [CocoaPods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/test-specs.html) has more details.

Comment: What strategy will you recommend if I want to run my private library tests together with my app tests?

Comment: The CocoaPods documentation states (link in the answer): "You may choose to have multiple test specs in a podspec if you'd like to describe different parts of your pod with different test sources and dependencies."